# How to override User Defined Variable from JSR223 PreProcessor in Jmetr?

Tags: variables, jmeter, jsr223

I have a such problem

Here is my User defined variables:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DTlU4.png

And here is my script from JSR223 PreProcessor:

```java
def params = []
def attributes = [:]
Random random = new Random()

def int variantToStartFrom = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("START_FROM"))
def int increment = variantToStartFrom + Integer.parseInt(vars.get("INCREMENT"))

for (int i = 3; i <= 3; i++) {
  for (int j = variantToStartFrom; j <= increment; j++) {
    def attr = [:]
    attr.put('location_id', i)
    attr.put('variant_id', j)
    attr.put('quantity', random.nextInt(100000))
    params.add(attr)
  }
}

attributes.put('items', params)

def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(attributes)
vars.put("START_FROM", increment.toString())

sampler.addNonEncodedArgument("", json.toPrettyString(), "")
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

As result I'm trying to run Thread group two times

My idea is to override my `START_FROM` var in User Defined Variable so then new Thread group run will use `START_FROM + 1` value

Is `vars.put("START_FROM", increment.toString())` should work as I expected? Or is there any other way how to override User Defined Variable from script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected. Your script will change the value of `START_FROM` after running script, but it only happens while running. When test finish and re-run the test, `STAT_FROM` will be back to value that defined in GUI, it's is 1.

To sum up, you can change the value while running test, you can't change the value you've already typed in GUI.

Comment: Oh... I didn't noticed that during the script running it actually increment value and then rollback it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. As per [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) documentation

   > Note that all the UDV elements in a test plan - no matter where they are - are **processed at the start**.
2. As per [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) documentation:

   > Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread;** properties are common to all threads, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

So whenever you change a variable it's being changed only in current thread (virtual user) context. Another Thread Group will read the value you specified in the User Defined Variables.

I think you should rather go for [Counter test element or __counter() function](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-counter) instead or write the new incremented value into a file and read it either with Groovy or using [CSV Data Set config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) or via [__StringFromFile() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__StringFromFile) or whatever is the suitable way.